# How can I configure vim syntax highlighting for mako templates?

Tags: python, vim, mako

I'd like to get the HTML elements highlighted as well as the MAKO / Python elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1858) should (at least) highlight the mako elements.